# Проверить, имеется ли данная подстрока в каждом элементе массива строк

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки

Имеется массив строк, необходимо проверить содержится ли некая подстрока в каждом элементе массива строк, в случае, если хоть в одной строке ее нет, нужно вернуть false.

Алгоритм до ужаса простой, но задание требует от решения минимум символов в коде.

Есть ли какие-нибудь компактные конструкции для решения этой задачи в javascript? Язык начал трогать совсем недавно.

Эта штука нужна для проверки в блоке if-else.

Comment: Короче всего код через регулярные выражения.

Comment: Добавьте пример массива, что бы проще было написать решение, а не сочинять свой массив, что займет гораздо-больше времени

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const test = ['тест', 'тестировщик','те2ст'];
const test2 = ['тест', 'тестировщик','тестовый'];
let result = test.every(elem => ~elem.indexOf('тест'));
let result2 = test2.every(elem => ~elem.indexOf('тест'));
console.log(result);
console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Возьмем к примеру этот массив:

```
var test = ['Привет0', 'Привет1', 'Привет2', 'При_вет3'];
```

Если нужно проверить, содержится ли подстрока 'Привет' в каждом элементе массива, используем эту функцию:

```
function include(array, key) {
    var regexp = new RegExp(key, 'g');
    return array.join(' ').match(regexp).length == array.length;
}
console.log(include(test, 'Привет')); // false
```